# Typehint method as returning return type of other method in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a base class:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod

class Thing:
    @abstractmethod
    def _process(self):
        ...

    def process(self, x: int):
        self.pre_process(x)
        return self._process()
```

How do I typehint `process` as returning the return type of `_process`?  My first thought was something like:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar

class Thing:
    T = TypeVar("T")

    @abstractmethod
    def _process(self) -> T:
        ...

    def process(self, x: int) -> T:
        ...
```

But mypy 1.3.0 complains quite rightly that `T` is only present once in the function signature:

```py
> mypy /tmp/t.py
...
error: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar
...
```

Comment: Which mypy version and arguments are you using? mypy 0.950 without any arguments does not complain.

Comment: @mkrieger1 fails for me with 1.3.0, output added sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Thing` inherit `Generic[T]`.

```
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Generic
from abc import abstractmethod

T = TypeVar("T")

class Thing(Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def _process(self) -> T:
        ...

    def process(self, x: int) -> T:
        return self._process()
```

```
> mypy /tmp/t.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Now you can inherit from `Thing` like this:

```
class A(Thing[list]):
    def _process(self) -> list:
        return []
```

Comment: ...and it looks like there's a [pep](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) to land a saner syntax soon.  Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.